# force http to https for specific subfolders using web.config IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, windows-server-2008

On a VPS using Windows 2006 R2 I am wanting to edit the web.config file so that all pages found within several subfolders are redirected from http to https.

I've found this suggestion below and what I would like to know is how to list the specific folders where this rewrite rule would then be applied.

The subfolders are:

/secure1/

/secure2/

/admin1/

/admin2/

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi there NepCoder, thanks for your solution. I'll try this out later today and feedback.

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Hey there!Thanks for the follow up. It's been a mad busy week and I meant to report back earlier. The code is spot on... the server rewrite module however is another matter LOL. Having researched a little it appears that there are work arounds but they require a level of expertise that currently I do not have. I'll be migrating the site to a windows 2012 environment in a few months and I'll test everything again then. Thanks again for your assistance :)

Comment: That is great to hear. If it worked for you then would you mind accepting my answer? This will be helpful for others if they are in a similar situation. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(secure1|secure2|admin1|admin2).*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Got the information from this url if you would like to learn more: 
https://forums.iis.net/t/1176994.aspx?Https+Redirect+for+certain+folders+sections+only